# Adding rails engine outside the app folder and pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a rails app called recipe . And I have a rails engine 'blogo' with this folder.Both recipe and blogo is in a folder 'foodsy'. In my gemfile , blogo is loaded with

```
gem 'blogo' ,path : '../blogo'
```

But when I push the app to heroku , I get an error saying

```
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        The path `/tmp/blogo` does not exist.
remote:        Bundler Output: The path `/tmp/blogo` does not exist.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to secure-gorge-6009.
```

I think this is because the git initialized in recipe folder doesnt include blogo. If I push it from the foodsy folder I get the following error

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby
```

Because there is no ruby file in the foodsy folder, it gives this error. How can I include the blogo folder in the recipe git ?